keep getting mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'testing'@'localhost' (using password: YES) for non-root users
I have a linux web server as a part of a college course (i.e, all of my applications and setting are done according to my teacher instructions, and I get the needed files from his ftp server). I'm pretty sure my server uses linux 4.4.14, and I access it using teraTerm.
I've set up a phpmyadmin and mariaDB on my server. I can log in to my website on phpmyadmin as root, using the password I've set on my server. The problem is I can't log in as any user I created through phpmyadmin. I keep getting "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'testing'@'localhost' (using password: YES)", and "Cannot log in to the MySQL server".
Trying to log as another user
My config.inc.php file
My useres shown in phpmyadmin. I can't delete the any users, and keep getting error from them, but at this point I don't care
I've tried creating differnet users through phpmyadmin, using different passwords and usernames. None of which managed to log. I've went over my config.inc.php, adding and removing parts, including changing the auth-type, adding root to the user field and adding my root password. So far, the most I've managed is to make the site to fall.
EDIT: I've tried adding a user with grant:yes, and I still can't connect with it
EDIT2: Added to my config.inc.php the line: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = 'true/false'; and now I can log as other users, but only without a password. I don't understand why I can log without a password for any user but root, or why both true and false cause that. I've tried leaving it empty, but that made it not log with or without password for non-root users

First you need to create a username specifically like 'testing'@'localhost'
Then you need to do a
grant all privileges on database_name.* to 'testing'@'localhost';

If you are on the same machine using the same localhost.  If you are coming from an a different IP you will need to create a separate username for the other IP.
addendum
Try resetting your root password.
You can login without a password because you didn't assign a password for the username.
Root fails because it has a defined password.  So no password obviously fails, and then the password version fails because the password is somehow wrong.
Even though it has the name root, it is a totally different account from the root username you used to login to the computer.
If you have another account with mysql admin permissions
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html
CREATE USER 'username'@'host' IDENTIFIED WITH authentication_plugin BY 'password';
Also don't forget.
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

